# Entity Framework connection failed to postgres: "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, azure-functions, npgsql

I am testing an Azure function project in a local environment, using Npgsql as a driver to postgres, connection strings defined in local.settings.json instead of App.config.

When I set Npgsql as the provider for Entity Framework and set the default connection factory to `NpgsqlConnectionFactory`, reading a `DbSet` in the `DbContext` produces the following error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. -> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) -> The system cannot find the file specified

Here is my `DbContext`:

```
public partial class PostgresContext : DbContext
{
    public PostgresContext() : base("postgres-key")
    {

    }
}

public class NpgSqlConfiguration:DbConfiguration
{
    public NpgSqlConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderFactory("Npgsql",NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

Here is my connection string:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "postgres-key": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"
  }
}
```

I have tried replacing the Server section of the connection string with localhost, checking to see if the postgres 64 service is running, checked that port 5432 is open, checking whether Entity Framework works with `local.settings.json`.

The only way I have been able to move forward was creating my own `NpgsqlConnection` for manual database queries. I am trying to avoid plan B as much as possible and would appreciate any assistance in getting the ORM working.

Update: using .net framework 4.7.1

Comment: Is your database provisioned in Azure?

Comment: No I am only testing upon a localhost database.

Comment: Are you sure your database in running and port `5432` is open?

Comment: I checked the postgres x64 service is running and ran `netstat -an` in powershell to determine the ports status. It had the state of LISTENING.

Comment: Also I should add, I can access the database from a python website's debug test, using the same connection string.

Comment: Have you checked `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Yes. The error points towards a network malfunction so I should update the question with my tests. Previous question was assuming this was an entity framework issue.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure whether it's not an issue with the fact, that connection string is in `local.settings.json`, which may be problematic for EF. I'd have to check this, but I'd need to have a full repro.

Comment: I believe that it has no issues with local.settings.json, since it can be found in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` at runtime and fouling the connection string returns a 'bad connection string'-ish error while accessing EF.

Comment: Tested using the Dapper object relational mapper instead of Entity Framework. It works!

Comment: Is this .net core? what versions of EF are you using?

Comment: .net framework 4.7.1

Comment: The exception message clearly indicates that EF is trying to connect to SQL Server. Are you sure the `NpgSqlConfiguration` is in effect? e.g. if you put a breakpoint inside the constructor, is it hit?

Comment: I can confirm that the class inheriting `dbconfiguration` was instantiated during startup. from this classes documentation: `A class derived from this class can be placed in the same assembly as a class derived from DbContext to define Entity Framework configuration for an application. `

Comment: I know what the documentation says. The question was whether that *actually* happens. May be Azure Function project works differently, who knows. The only way I can get similar exception in a "normal" project is when I comment out that configuration class and App.settings. And again, the exception message you posted contains *"...while establishing a connection to **SQL Server**..."*, so definitely the Npgsql configuration is not in effect.

Comment: Can you try to move the connection string a traditional web.config. Since you are using .net 4.7.x and not .net core, do you have a startup class? if you are can you show it. Are you using DI? Appsettings.json was introduced in .net core, and originally there was confusion because many thought EF could pick up the ConnStr from the json file too, instead we needed to configure it in a Startup class or use DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited my reproduction of the issue thanks to the surge of helpers recently. I managed to get it working when [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856151/entityframework-npgsql-dbconfiguration-doesnt-work) made me realize, I had omitted `DbConfiguration.SetProviderServices()` from the dbconfiguration inheritor. The npgsql documentation is terrible since it failed to mention this was required.

```
public class NpgSqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public NpgSqlConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderFactory("Npgsql", NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("Npgsql", provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

here is my full reproduction (if anyone runs into a similar issue in the future):
https://bitbucket.org/DCDprivate/entityframeworkissuereproduction

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. I am not familiar with .net, however, according to Npgsql's official document, the connection string looks like this:

```
"Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase"
```

While yours is:

```
"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"
```

Why not use same parameters? Such as:

```
"Host=127.0.0.1;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=postgres"
```

refer to this link: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

And please make sure it listen on all interfaces or lo interface, you can try"

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5432
```

to make sure connectivity be working